# LibreOffice supporting links between slides in a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

When a PowerPoint presentation (*.pptx* file) has internal links between slides, it is possible to get LibreOffice Impress to support these — such that the user displaying the presentation can be taken to different slides depending on where they click?

Here's [a PowerPoint presentation which does that](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1CMQ_JdkyUZ4DhuM3UMSyxEZIQE7_NiP9/edit#slide=id.p5), and still does it when viewed in Google Slides: to see it, press the ‘Present’ button, then see how on slide 5 clicking each of ‘Scales’ and ‘Fur’ go to different places.

But when I download that file and load it into LibreOffice, the interaction has disappeared: clicking anywhere on slide 5 just proceeds to slide 6. This happens whether I download the *.pptx* file directly, or using Google Slides's option to download it as an ODP document.

Is there any way to convert or display a PowerPoint presentation on Linux with working internal links? Thanks.

I'm running LibreOffice 7.0.4.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: First, does Impress support inter-slide links itself? That is, can you create links between slides IN Impress? If not, then of course it's not going to support links created in another program. Next, try saving directly from PPT to ODP to eliminate two possibly unnecessary conversion steps along the way (PPT to Google Slides, Google Slides to ODP). If you don't have access to PowerPoint and would like to see if PPT to ODP to You works, let me know and I'll create a simple presentation for you to test.

Comment: Yes: in Impress, select one of the text objects that's lost its link, then ‘Insert ▸ Hyperlink… ▸ Document ▸ Target’, click on the target icon, and pick a slide. I don't have PowerPoint (I'm running on Linux). If you can save as ODP (or even PPT-without-the-X), I can try that. Thanks.

Comment: You're on, but promise you'll report back as to the results. Enquiring minds and all that. This link points to a folder on OneDrive with a test presentation saved to PPTX, PPT, XML and ODP ... basically, anything I thought might be remotely useful.  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am2R87k-gmnpiSGLF4ijoyimW401?e=UAncOR

Comment: Thank you, Steve. LibreOffice followed the links in the ODP file, but neither the PPT nor PPTX. So it looks like I'd need the provider of a PowerPoint presentation to resave it in ODP format themselves. I didn't even know MS supported ODP (thanks), but it seems they do that better than LibreOffice supports PPT(X).

Comment: I'm glad to hear that that worked. It'd be valuable to the LibreOffice community if you'd report this to the developers, I suspect. Feel free to send along the sample files I made, if that'll help them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check their bug-tracker and see if it's already reported …